# how to get the colorpicker value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, color-picker

How could I get the colorpicker value in an input with on change of red, green, blue colours? 
http://jsbin.com/alefok/1/edit

```
<body>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="swatch" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
<input type="text" id="colour">
<script>
  $(".ui-slider-handle").on('change', function(){
var valA = $("#red").slider("value");
var valB = $("#green").slider("value");
var valC = $("#blue").slider("value");
$("#colour").append(valA+","+ valB+","+ valC)
})
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it on the `refreshSwatch` function which will trigger on the `slide` and `change` events of jQuery UI's slider along when the `background-color` is being updated.

```
function refreshSwatch(evt, ui) {
    var red = $("#red").slider("value"),
        green = $("#green").slider("option", "value"),
        blue = $("#blue").slider("value"),
        hex = hexFromRGB(red, green, blue);
    $("#swatch").css("background-color", "#" + hex);
    $("#colour").val("#" + hex);
}
```

Using these events will let you perform live updates. You can adjust the format of the value set to the text input.

[See it here.](http://jsbin.com/alefok/4/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your event binding as below: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/alefok/10/edit)

```
<script>
      $("#red, #green, #blue").on('slidestop', function(){
        var valA = $("#red").slider("value");
        var valB = $("#green").slider("value");
        var valC = $("#blue").slider("value");
        $("#colour").val(valA+","+ valB+","+ valC)
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the BG of the swach:

```
$('#red, #blue, #green').change(function(){

    $('#swatch').css('background-color');

});
```